# Very Simple Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

Does anybody have any suggestions as to where I could get a really simple gallery (projected below) that uses the basic html framework of the following snippet? **A previous-next gallery**

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="image01.jpg" width="500" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image02.jpg" width="200" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image03.jpg" width="530" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image04.jpg" width="500" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image05.jpg" width="178" height="340"></li>
  <li><img src="image06.jpg" width="400" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image07.jpg" width="300" height="220"></li>
  <li><img src="image08.jpg" width="400" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image09.jpg" width="500" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image10.jpg" width="400" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image11.jpg" width="300" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image12.jpg" width="300" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image13.jpg" width="178" height="340"></li>
  <li><img src="image14.jpg" width="500" height="450"></li>
  <li><img src="image15.jpg" width="200" height="220"></li>
  <li><img src="image16.jpg" width="100" height="450"></li>
</ul>
```

[alt text http://www.zip-cover.com/development/image_carosoul/slideshow.jpg](http://www.zip-cover.com/development/image_carosoul/slideshow.jpg)

Thank You, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 
 [galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/) Much better than galleria if u want functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[JAlbum](http://jalbum.net/) is a good program to generate such galleries. You can add your own skins.

Comment: I would like something with more control over the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The [Galleria plugin](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/) for jQuery uses simple markup like that, and it's very slick.